# Need to add a row identifier for matching values using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to come up with a query/way to set a primary contact on a table.

Basically I need to match accounts to master accounts and set the name of the primary contact to all the accounts that match.

I know I can do this by reading the table to a C# code, but I am wondering if its possible by using a stored procedure. Anything that can guide me to a solution will help.

Information that I have:

```
account   | master account | Account Name
----------+----------------+-------------
9999      | 99999          | Joe Smith
3333      | 99999          | Jim Smith
1343      | 99999          | Jane Smith 
5555      | 88888          | Bla Bla
```

What I am trying to accomplish:

```
account    | master account | Name         | Primary Contact
-----------+----------------+--------------+----------------
9999       | 99999          | Joe Smith    | Joe Smith
3333       | 99999          | Jim Smith    | Joe Smith
1343       | 99999          | Jane Smith   | Joe Smith
5555       | 77777          | Bla bla      | Bla bla
```

Comment: :for setting the primary contact in your result, do you have criteria or just get the name update on each account by self joining to the same table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update a
set primaryContact = b.Name
from accountTable a
inner join accountTable b
on b.account = a.masterAccount
```

This updates the accountTable, setting the primary contact to be the name associated with the account's master account's record.